# External Partitioning in hive according to year,month and date format

Tags: azure, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am using microsoft azure HDInsight. I have the data in the below format.

container/folder/year/month/date/file1.csv

container/folder/year/month/date/file2.csv
.
.
.and so on.

I created an external table with partitions using below queries

```
'drop table partition;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE partition (id string, event timestamp and so on)
PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE'
```

Got the output that the query submitted was successful and external table was created.

Then gave the Alter command to add the partition.

```
'ALTER TABLE partition ADD PARTITION(year=2014, month=1, day=1)
 LOCATION'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/folderName/2014/01/01';'
```

Did not get any errors even here.

Then when i gave a simple select statement, i couldn't retrieve anything from the data files.

```
'select * from partition where year=2014 AND month=01 AND day=01 limit 10;'
```

and also tried

```
'select * from partition limit 10;'
```

Both the select statement did not return anything. Unable to figure what went wrong. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Just a quick question. In your CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE you are specifying `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'` but your filenames appear to be CSV.  Are the files actually JSON encoded?

Comment: Yes they are in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data files are stored in blob storage at a Uri like:

```
https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/folderName/2014/01/01
```

then your wasb: uri needs to be:

```
wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net/folderName/2014/01/01
```

or if this is the default storage account/container for your cluster you can just use:

```
wasb:///folderName/2014/01/01
```

The extra `containerName` in your ALTER TABLE wasb: above might be throwing things off by pointing to paths that are effectively empty.